# Bootstrap: combine Pagination with dynamic tabbed interfaces Bug

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I´ve a problem. I tried to combine Bootstrap Pagination with dynamic tabbed interfaces form Bootstap Navs. First it´s working, but after some clicks on them the links doesn´t work anymore. 
If i click on them, they don´t switch the tabs.
Is there a problem with the id anchor?

```
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">Test</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">Test2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">Test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: visit this link:-https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/tabs/

Comment: I tried the hints on the page and checked the code to see if there were any differences to mine. It didn't help :(